# Find the center and the radius of convergence of this complex series.

Tags: sequences-and-series

$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^{n}}{(2n)!} (z - \frac{1}{2}\pi)^{2n}$$
$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{(2(n+1))!} (z - \frac{1}{2}\pi)^{2n}$$

So I know a power series is $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} a_n(z-z_0)^n = a_0 + a_1(z-z_0) + a_2(z-z_0)^n...$ and that the radius is going to equal $\lim_{n \to \infty} \left | \frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}\right |$ and if that value converges to 0, the radius is \infty.

So $\lim_{n \to \infty} \left | \frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}\right | = \left | \frac{(-1)^n}{(2n)!)}\right | \cdot \left | \frac{(2n+2)!}{(-1)^{n+1}}\right |$

So since the absolute value of (-1) is 1, we can say that portion is just equal to $1^n$ and they cancel.

Can someone help me finish the rest? IS the numerator just left with $(2n+1)(2n+2)$ so does this limit approach infinity?

What about this next problem .How do I get this into the correct form?

$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} (\frac{(2-i)}{(1+5i)}) z^n$$

Answer (score 1):

You offer two power series, but then write as if there were only one. It is rather confusing what you mean by including the second series. But I'll join you in ignoring its existence in favor of the first. There are a couple issues your use of the Ratio test here.

The first is that in the Ratio test $a_n$ refers to the coefficient of the $(z - c)^n$ term, not the term of index $n$ in however the series is expressed, as you have interpreted it here. Therefore
$$a_n = \begin{cases}\dfrac{(-1)^{n/2}}{n!}, &n \text{ even}\\0,&n\text{ odd}\end{cases}$$
And $\left|\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}\right|$ thus flips back and forth between being $0$ and being undefined, so the Ratio test fails.

However this is actually a simple problem to overcome in this case. Let $w = \left(z -\frac \pi 2\right)^2$. The series becomes $$\sum_{n=0}^\infty \dfrac{(-1)^n}{(2n)!}w^n$$ which is a power series to which the Ratio test can successfully be applied. But you have to be careful. When you find the radius of convergence $R$, that is the radius of the power series in $w$, not the power series in $z -\frac \pi 2$. The radius of convergence for the $z$ power series will be $\sqrt R$. (Do you see why?)

The second issue is simpler: you made a mistake in applying the formula

$$\left|\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}\right|\ne \left | \frac{(-1)^n}{(2n)!)}\right | \cdot \left | \frac{(2n+2)!}{(-1)^{n+1}}\right |$$
Examine it carefully to spot the problem.

---

Your second question is also unclear. What more "correct form" are you looking for? It is in the traditional form for a power series already.

Comment: Actually, looking back over your question, you apparently are also confused by what the Ratio test actually says. That is, which ratio gives the radius of convergence, and which if it goes to $0$ means the radius is infinite. They are the not the same ratios in each statement.